# Matlab: Storing large numbers in Matlab

Tags: matlab, floating-point, precision, double-precision

For storing large numbers I am refering to the next:

```
2.7182818284590455348848081484902650117874145507812500
```

I can´t save this with [double precision floating-point format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision_floating-point_format) (IEEE754)

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The symbolic toolbox has the ability to hold variable precission arithmetic as strings.

```
x = sym('exp(1)');
vpa(x,500)

2.7182818284590452353602874713526624977572470936999595749669676277240766303535475945713821785251664274274663919320030599218174135966290435729003342952605956307381323286279434907632338298807531952510190115738341879307021540891499348841675092447614606680822648001684774118537423454424371075390777449920695517027618386062613313845830007520449338265602976067371132007093287091274437470472306969772093101416928368190255151086574637721112523897844250569536967707854499699679468644549059879316368892300987931
```